# Plotting single plots from mcmcglmm package in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following object obtained by the mcmcglmm package in R

```
> str(mcmc.list(results3[,2]))
List of 2
 $ :Class 'mcmc'  atomic [1:4000] 1.637 0.869 0.44 1.088 0.652 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1e+05 5e+05 1e+02
 $ :Class 'mcmc'  atomic [1:4000] 1.068 0.472 0.851 1.549 0.927 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 1e+05 5e+05 1e+02
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "mcmc.list"
>
```

and I can plot a graph to look like this:

```
plot(results3[,2])
```

[image]

I would like to be able to plot just the graph on the right (the distribution) but can't figure out how (what's infuriating is I managed it last week - with no problems - but have forgotten how, and tried many variants over the last hour). Do you know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled across a solution by trial and error:

```
plot(density(c(results3[,2][[1]],results3[,2][[2]])))
```

(More elegant answers will be accepted as the answer)